# Cannot run Xamarin UWP App in Release mode

Tags: xamarin, uwp, crash, release

I am currently working on a multi-platform Xamarin app, targeting iOS and UWP. Everything is fine on iOS, but I have trouble deploying on Windows in Release mode.

In Debug mode, there is no problem. My app can be compiled, deployed and packaged.
In Release, I can compile my project, but it crashes at start, with this output:

```
The program '[1820] MyProject.exe' has exited with code -1073741189 (0xc000027b).
Activation of the Windows Store app 'MyProjectFullNamePackage!App' failed with error 'Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80040905'.
```

I spent days looking for a solution on internet, and I tried to :

- Create a package in Release mode and install it on another PC
- Compile with Native debugger to get more log
- Change my SDK version
- Clean, delete bin/obj, delete .vs, restart VS, rebuilding etc
- Restore Nuget packages
- Increase the app version

And almost everything I found on forums...

UWP Target version: 1903 (Build 18362)
UWP Min version: 1803 (Build 17134)
My OS SDK version: 17134

Xamarin: up to date.

:(

Comment: Make sure you have the UWP project set to Deploy in the Configuration Manager (Build > Configuration Manager)(In the Configuration Manager window that opens, make sure the check box next to the UWP app project under the deploy column is checked)

Comment: I just checked and yes, the "deploy" checkbox is checked, for both Debug and Release

Comment: Try to create a new blank project , then run it in release mode to check if the issue still exists .